# Is it possible to upload file larger than 60mb using MS graph API?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to upload files (e.g. xx.pdf (70mb) in MS Teams channel using MS Graph API v1.0. but it fails if more than 60mb. is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, upload the file in chunks with each chunk being less than 60MB:

Upload bytes to the upload session To upload the file, or a portion of the file, your app makes a PUT request to the uploadUrl value received in the createUploadSession response. You can upload the entire file, or split the file into multiple byte ranges, as long as the maximum bytes in any given request is less than 60 MiB.

The fragments of the file must be uploaded sequentially in order. Uploading fragments out of order will result in an error.

Note: If your app splits a file into multiple byte ranges, the size of each byte range MUST be a multiple of 320 KiB (327,680 bytes). Using a fragment size that does not divide evenly by 320 KiB will result in errors committing some files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Just Asking. Will there be an error if the size of the last file in the sequence is lesser than 320KiB?

Comment: It's not very clear from the documentation, but I don't see how you could possibly have the last range be divisible by 320KiB in all circumstances, so I assume the last chunk can be the remainder of the file, whatever size it may be.

Comment: @Tom, so no file limit in size if i chunk it below 60 MiB?

Comment: @chubOo if the file is less than 60MiB it can be uploaded in a single request.